# PHP: How to get the highest value in mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a website with a little game, and I want to redirect people to the last lobby when them click a button, my code is like this:

```
<a href="lobby.php?id=<?php echo $lastlobby; ?>">
  <center><img src="/images/creategamebtn.png" onClick="host()" draggable="false" class="btn" style=""></center>
</a>
```

I want to make this button redirect to the last lobby id, from my mysql, I've tried this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `cflobbies`\n"  . 
       "ORDER BY `cflobbies`.`id` 
        DESC 
        LIMIT 0, 1 ";
```

How could I set the $lastlobby to be the highest id from the mysql table?
So when someone click the button to create a game they will go to the highest id, for example:

www.csgomew.com/lobby.php?id=330

If the 330 is the highest id.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: `LIMIT 1`, not `LIMIT 0,1`

Comment: "SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `cflobbies`"